# How do I handle mean average precision edge cases

Tags: math, machine-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I'm implementing a mean average precision (mAP) metric for a computer vision model that outputs bounding boxes for multiple classes and I need help understanding how to handle some of the edge cases.

Due to the nature of my question, the fact that it's a computer vision problem can be ignored.

It is clear to me that `mAP = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives)`, but what happens when `true_positives == false_positives == 0`? IE. if the output doesn't predict anything at all.

My current hypothesis it that if there were annotations that the algorithm just failed to predict, mAP should be 0, otherwise, if there weren't any annotations in the first place, it should be 1, but it seems a little counter-intuitive as this travels into the realm of Recall.

## Example 1:

```
Truth: 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
Pred.: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
mAP = 0 / (0 + 0) # ?
```

## Example 2:

```
Truth: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Pred.: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
mAP = 0 / (0 + 0) # ?
```

Since the model did not make any `true_positive` and `false_positive` calls in both scenarios, what should the mAP be for the two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://github.com/dice-group/gerbil/wiki/Precision,-Recall-and-F1-measure

> In some rare cases, the calculation of Precision or Recall can cause a
>   division by 0. Regarding the precision, this can happen if there are
>   no results inside the answer of an annotator and, thus, the true as
>   well as the false positives are 0. For these special cases, we have
>   defined that if the true positives, false positives and false
>   negatives are all 0, the precision, recall and F1-measure are 1. This
>   might occur in cases in which the gold standard contains a document
>   without any annotations and the annotator (correctly) returns no
>   annotations. If true positives are 0 and one of the two other counters
>   is larger than 0, the precision, recall and F1-measure are 0.